# HTTP/1.1 request with 401 response - postman error

Tags: html, postman, http-status-code-401

Problem Description:
I am trying to get an authorization on a device with a simple Digest Auth using Postman.
The sequence is working fine with a web browser, but Postman returns: Error aborted

I have tried multiple settings to mimic the working request. I have compared both on wireshark and they seems pratically identical.

It looks like the GET request is aborting before its completion.
[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiX5p.png)

Here is the wireshark snippet

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67wlS.png)

To debug the problem, I made a test app in Qt5 ( 5.12.5 ) and I get the same problem. The return status is 0 and no other information on the reply header is available.

There is something suspicious when doing the same kind of request with cURL ( in WSL2 )

[cURL example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvBUy.png)

Finally, I was able to get a proper request with Python3. I got the "Error 401 unauthorized" that I was expecting.

```py
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.0.150'
response = requests.get(url)

# Accessing low-level information
status_code = response.status_code
headers = response.headers
content = response.content
text = response.text

# Printing low-level information
print(f"Status Code: {status_code}")
print("Headers:")
for header, value in headers.items():
    print(f"  {header}: {value}")

print("\nContent:")
print(content)

print("\nText:")
print(text)
```

The problem here, is that I need it to work in Qt because I am developping a plugin and it needs to be in C++.

Anything I am missing ?